# plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) searches parent theme in ACF extension

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I wrote a plugin which adds additional functionality to Advanced Custom fields and the tinyMCE editor. All in all simple stuff with a bunch of js and css primarily.

Issue is that WP not only looks for the file in:

'/wp-content/plugins/acf-columns/assets/js/input.js?ver=1.0.0'

where it's actually located, but also:

'/wp-content/themes/generatepress/resources/acf-field-column/js/input.js'

Not only does it not look for the js file in the 'assets' folder, but it also looks for it in 'acf-field-column' folder, not 'acf-field-columns' (notice the 's' in columns). I'm using a child theme of GeneratePress.

I'm only enqueuing the files in the plugin master file, and only once

Heres my enqueue

```
// Add styles and js init
function acf_admin_enqueue() {
global $post;

if($post->post_type != 'acf-field-group'):

    // enqueue jquery UI script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

    // enqueue plugin jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pagebuilder-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/input.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );


    // enqueue stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pagebuilder-styles', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/css/input.css', array(), '1.0.0', false);
endif;
}

// hook in styles and js
add_action('acf/input/admin_head', 'acf_admin_enqueue');
```

I have no folder called 'resources' in my child theme, thats only in the generatepress parent theme.
Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: not sure if it is related by your handler names are very generic (jquery-ui especially very aweful) I would guess you have a collision of handler names that cause confusion

Comment: Just found the issue in one of the plugin files. It was just me not looking thoroughly enough. But thanks for the input. I should definitely change that handle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total dummy. Looked through the field file and found this:

```
function input_admin_enqueue_scripts()
{
    // Note: This function can be removed if not used


    // register acf scripts
    wp_register_script('acf-input-column', $this->settings['dir'] . 'js/input.js', array('acf-input'), $this->settings['version']);
    wp_register_style('acf-input-column', $this->settings['dir'] . 'css/input.css', array('acf-input'), $this->settings['version']);


    // scripts
    wp_enqueue_script(array(
        'acf-input-column',
    ));

    // styles
    wp_enqueue_style(array(
        'acf-input-column',
    ));

}
```

$settings->['dir'] was set to: get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/acf-field-column/'

So that's where the 404 files got included.